# Select as datas inferior a um determinado ano

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Como posso criar select para mostrar somente os funcionários de uma empresa que a foram admitidos antes de um determinado ano ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tipo anoAdmissao é date ou seja: `dd-mm-AA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Tfuncionario where EXTRACT (YEAR FROM anoAdmissao) < '2000'
```

A função extract foi usada para selecionar apenas o ano do campo anoAdmissao, e então compará-lo com o ano desejado.

Answer (score 1):

simples assim:

```
select * from tfuncionario where anoAdmissao < to_char('2000/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

utilizando `to_char` para formatar uma mascara.

aonde `'2000/01/01'` corresponde ao determinado período da pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui com esse trecho de código:

```
select * 
from tfuncionario F 
where F.ANOADMISSAO <= ('01/01/00');
```

Comment: show, é bom usar o to_char para garantir os valores

Comment: Este sql pode dar erro se os parâmetros da "section" tiverem sido alterados.